# Controlling 2nd cmd window - c#

Tags: c#, cmd, db2

I am trying to use DB2's Command Line processor.  When using it on the command line,  I enter:  db2cmd then a 2nd window opens where I can connect to the database and submit queries.  I am attempting to write a wrapper for the CLP and when I access the command line,  it opens the DB2 CLP in a 2nd window and I can't figure out how to send arguements to the new window.  Here is what I have:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Process();
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "db2cmd";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (var sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("DB2 CONNECT TO dbname USER \"username\" USING \"password\"");
            sw.WriteLine("DB2 SELECT * FROM SPYPRD.CLMDTL FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can write to the 2nd console's input stream because you can't set it's `RedirectStandardInput` property to true. One thing you could do is: Find the 1st console's children which will be the 2nd console, find its handle and send keystrokes to it. I'm sure i'm overcomplicating things, but that's the only way that comes into mind right now.

Comment: thank you,  I talked to a co-worker and using a handle was the only thing he could think of as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to use an alternative interface (e.g. the ADO .net interface) from C# instead of using the CLP.

To use commands like LOAD and EXPORT etc, from ADO (or jdbc/odbc etc) you invoke them via stored procedure SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD() if the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows. Pay attention to the details in the documentation for that stored procedure because all file names are relative to the Db2-server (not the workstation).

Not sure if CLP accepts stdin redirection for passwords - you would also need to parse the stdout, maybe messy.

If the database is *local* then you can use the CLP without needing a userid/password on the CONNECT statement. If you wish to connect with different credentials use runAs to specify the credentials independently of the CLP, to avoid needing to send arguments to the CLP.

If the database is remote and is on Linux/Unix/Windows, best to use an alternative interface than CLP (e.g. ADO etc), or consider shipping the script to the remote-server to run locally on the Db2-LUW server as the required-user again avoiding passwords(e.g. if the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, use tools equivalent to psexec or ssh etc).

Comment: Can ADO perform CLP functions such as exporting to an .ixf?